# Construct Binary tree from Preorder and inorder Optimized solution not working

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

For [Leetcode 105](https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-binary-tree-from-preorder-and-inorder-traversal/) I've got the `O(N^2)` solution working and I'm attempting to optimize to an `O(N)` solution but the output tree is the wrong structure.

> Given two integer arrays preorder and inorder where preorder is the preorder traversal of a binary tree and inorder is the inorder traversal of the same tree, construct and return the binary tree.

My original `O(N^2)` solution.

```py
def buildTree(self, preorder: List[int], inorder: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        preorder_queue = deque(preorder)
        def helper(preorder, inorder):
            if not preorder or not inorder:
                return None
            root = TreeNode(preorder.popleft())
            root_index = inorder.index(root.val)
            root.left = helper(preorder, inorder[:root_index])
            root.right = helper(preorder, inorder[root_index+1:])
            return root
        return helper(preorder_queue, inorder)
```

The slow operation is here is the `inorder.index(root.val)` since an `index` operation in a list is `O(N)`. I'm trying to optimize this by storing a map of `Node values -> indexes` in my solution below.

```py
def buildTree(self, preorder: List[int], inorder: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        preorder_queue = deque(preorder)
        cache = {}
        for i, node_val in enumerate(inorder):
            cache[node_val] = i
        def helper(preorder, inorder):
            if not preorder or not inorder:
                return None
            root = TreeNode(preorder.popleft())
            root_index = cache[root.val]
            root.left = helper(preorder, inorder[:root_index])
            root.right = helper(preorder, inorder[root_index+1:])
            return root
        return helper(preorder_queue, inorder)
```

However for the input `preorder = [3,9,20,15,7]` and `inorder = [9,3,15,20,7]` my output is giving me `[3,9,20,null,null,15,null,7]` instead of the correct tree structure `[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`. Can anyone explain what's wrong with the cache solution?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the different output is this:

In the first version the value of `root_index` is taken from the **local** name `inorder`, which in general is just a **slice** of the original `inorder` (see how the recursive call is made with such a slice as argument). So the value of `root_index` is an index that is meaningful to the slice, but not to the overall, initial `inorder` list. Yet the second version of the code will give `root_index` an index that is meaningful in the initial `inorder` list, not to the local slice of it.

You can fix that by not creating a local `inorder` name (as parameter), but instead pass `start` and `end` indices which define which slice should be assumed, without actually creating it. That way the code can continue with the initial `inorder` list and use the indexing that the `cache` offers.

So:

```
    def helper(preorder, start, end):
        if not preorder or start >= end:
            return None
        root = TreeNode(preorder.popleft())
        root_index = cache[root.val]
        root.left = helper(preorder, start, root_index)
        root.right = helper(preorder, root_index+1, end)
        return root
    return helper(preorder_queue, 0, len(inorder))
```